# Class cast exception while iterating over List<Long>

Tags: java

iam trying to iterate list of long type but iam getting:-

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

here is my piece of code:--

```
for(Long organid : patientTypesBean.getOrganList()){ // Exception in this line
 //... 
}
```

patientTypesBean.getOrganList() returns arrayList of Long type. I even try for loop but same problem

```
for(int i=0;i<patientTypesBean.getOrganList().size();i++){
        System.out.println("--------------Value is---->"+patientTypesBean.getOrganList().get(i));
        patientOrganEntity.getOrganListID().setParameterListID(patientTypesBean.getOrganList().get(i)); // here i get exception
    }
```

seeking for help. thanks in advance

Edited:-

```
List<Long> organList = new ArrayList<Long>();
public List<Long> getOrganList() {
    return organList;
}

public void setOrganList(List<Long> organList) {
    this.organList = organList;
}
```

Comment: Can you show code of getOrganList?

Comment: Please add some code for getOrganList and Error log.

Comment: I just edited my question plaese have look @jens.

Comment: If you construct `organList` as you posted, it is not possibile to obtain that exception. Are you sure you're not using the list without Generics somewhere in your code? Have you compilation warning?

Comment: **1)** take your mouse over *getOrganList()* and it will in a pop-up show return type (could me some typo directing to a different method)
----------
**2)** write a SOP -system.out.println and just print it ,  patientTypesBean.getOrganList().toString() (this will get you a idea of the value contained in a better way)

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long this all m getting @jani

Comment: @Subodh Can you please ad the stacktrace?

Comment: What type is setParameterListID's parameter ?

Comment: I guess, your ArrayList has some object which is of type String. Double check where you are populating the ArrayList.

Comment: Can you try this once

Comment: try what ? my arraylist is of Long type. i even check this on debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this once,

```
for(int i=0;i<patientTypesBean.getOrganList().size();i++){
    Long organ = Long.valueOf(patientTypesBean.getOrganList().get(i));
    patientOrganEntity.getOrganListID().setParameterListID(organ);
}
```